# How authenticate to xiaomi mi band 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, xiaomi

I've generated an Android app that finds ble devices around it. And I can even connect temporarily up to 30 seconds, But after 30 seconds, the connection is lost. For example, I want to read the heart beat rate from Xiaomi Mi band 5 , but it needs authentication.